# list displaying slightly off centered

Tags: html, css, html-lists

I can't seem to figure out why my list is displaying slightly off center. I have some text below it in the same container that is 100% centered but the list seems to be padded slightly form the left. I am a novice at CSS, so perhaps someone can point where I've gone wrong. Much appreciated!

Here is the HTML

```
<div id="footer_menu">
<ul id="navlist">
<li><a href="#">HOME</a></li>
<li>|</li>
<li><a href="#">ABOUT</a></li>
<li>|</li>
<li><a href="#">ARCHIVE</a></li>
<li>|</li>
<li><a href="#">GET INVOLVED</a></li>
<li>|</li>
<li><a href="#">BLOG</a></li>
<li>|</li>
<li><a href="#">CONTACT</a></li>
</ul>
<font style="font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; font-size:10px">ALL CONTENT PRODUCED BY <img src="images/dblzerofilms.jpg" width="190" height="13" /> COPYRIGHT 2011</font>
</div>
```

here is the CSS

```
#footer_menu{
    position: relative;
    height: 75px;
    width: 1023px;
    bottom: 150px;
    margin-right: auto;
    margin-left: auto;
    text-align: center;
    font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #000;
}
#footer {
    height:75px;
    width:1024px;
    background-image: url(images/footer_img.jpg);
    position: relative;
    bottom: 0px;
}
#navlist li
{
    display: inline;
    list-style-type: none;
    padding-right: 5px;
    font-size: 11px;
}
#navlist li a
{
    font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    color: #000;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-weight: lighter;
    font-size: 11px;
}
```

Comment: Semantically, I normally like using `text-transform: uppercase` instead of putting the text in all caps in the HTML.

Comment: Also, CSS classes that contain more than one word are usually linked with hyphens, not underscores.

Comment: try #navlist { width: 1024px; margin: 0 auto; }

Comment: That's not really a font tag I see is it?? :)

Comment: Placing pipes in an li is not the best. Either use a border or the pseudo element of ::after.

Answer (score 4):

All you need to do is add the following line to your CSS rule:

```
#navlist {padding:0}
```

and that will remove that extra left padding that you have. I tried to fix your css code a little bit using shorthand css lines (i.e. margin and font), hope that helps:

```
#footer_menu{
    height:75px;
    margin:0 auto;
    text-align:center;
    font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    text-decoration:none;
    color:#000;
}
#footer {
    height:75px;
    width:1024px;
    background-image: url('images/footer_img.jpg');
}
#navlist {padding:0}
#navlist li {
    display:inline;
    list-style-type:none;
    padding-right:5px;
    font-size:11px;
}
#navlist li a {
    font:lighter 11px Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    color:#000;
    text-decoration:none;
}
```

Comment: this was the closest. It was as simple as adding 0 padding and 0 margins to ul#navlist

Answer (score 1):

Add this style

```
#navlist
{
   clear: left;
    padding: 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not a huge fan of putting spacers inside of my `<li>` elements. Normally if I need to do what you're trying to do, I use `<p>` tags instead. See my code below:

HTML:

```
<div id="footer-menu">
    <p><a href="#">Home</a> | <a href="#">About</a> | <a href="#">Archive</a> | <a href="#">Get Involved</a> | Blog | <a href="#">Contact</a></p>
    <p>All content produced by <img src="images/dblzerofilms.jpg" width="190" height="13" /> Copyright 2011</p>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
#footer-menu {
    font: 11px/1 Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    text-align: center;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    color: #000; }
#footer-menu a {
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #000;
    margin: 0 5px;
    display: inline-block; }
```

Preview: http://jsfiddle.net/Wexcode/Lb9XC/