# DIV UL content not centering within the UL

Tags: html, css, html-lists, center

I am working on an email for a client and this list/table has me stumped. here is the visual display.

[image: Screenshot of my current result]

As you can see, I have essentially 3 columns, each made by a separate `<ul>`. The problem is that they are not aligned with the `<h3>` above. when I click on the `<ul>` in the live view of DW I can see that the content is right-aligned.

[image: right-aligned li content within ul]

```css
.navlist {
  background-color: #99a6b1;
  height: 400px;
  padding-top: 50px;
}
.navlist ul {
  display: inline-table;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
.navlist li {
  list-style-type: none;
  color: #ececed;
  font-size: 16px;
  padding-bottom: 10px;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<section>
  <div class="navlist" align="center">
    <h3 style="color: #ececed; padding-bottom: 20px;">Our Commitment</h3>
    <ul>
      <li>
        <img src="https://static1.squarespace.com/static/5756358501dbae2c96b689fe/t/5829efb69de4bb1fe2fd2a37/1479143354215/V3DG+Web+Icons-04.png?format=300w" alt "comprehensive services" height="150px">
      </li>
      <li>ComprehensivevServices</li>
    </ul>
    <ul>
      <li>
        <img src="https://static1.squarespace.com/static/5756358501dbae2c96b689fe/t/5829efc329687f358474b73a/1479143366452/V3DG+Web+Icons-05.png?format=300w" alt "Dependable Support" height="150px">
      </li>
      <li>Dependable Service</li>
    </ul>
    <ul>
      <li>
        <img src="https://static1.squarespace.com/static/5756358501dbae2c96b689fe/t/5829efd0414fb518a2c06557/1479143379620/?format=300w" alt "Easy To Work With" height="150px">
      </li>
      <li>Easy To Work With</li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</section>
```

I would just like it to line up the way it should. Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: May I ask why you are using lists for this layout?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [list displaying slightly off centered](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8622498/list-displaying-slightly-off-centered)

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried removing the padding of your 'ul'?

```
.navlist ul{
    display: inline-table;
    margin: 0 auto;
    padding-left: 0;
}
```

That will center a bit more your content.

Comment: Thanks David! I tried this,  but it just squeezes all of the content closer to the center image, so they actually don't display any closer to the center.

Comment: @AlexBradley This answer _does_ solve your question. But I believe you may be confused by the fact that the leftmost list item is wider than the rightmost, so that the second list item is not exactly in the center under the text "Our Commitment". Even if the whole list is.

Comment: The solution would be to give all three list items the same width.

Answer (score 0):

Add `padding-left: 0` to `.navlist ul`

To keep the distance between the li items, you ca add some margin left AND right:

```
.navlist ul{
    display: inline-table;
    margin: 0 10px;
    padding-left: 0;
}
```

```css
.navlist {
 background-color: #99a6b1;
 height: 400px;
 padding-top: 50px;
}
.navlist ul{
 display: inline-table;
 margin: 0 10px;
  padding-left: 0;
}
.navlist li {
list-style-type: none;
 color: #ececed;
 font-size: 16px;
 padding-bottom: 10px;
 text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<section>
  <div class="navlist" align="center">
   <h3 style="color: #ececed; padding-bottom: 20px;">Our Commitment</h3>
   <ul>
    <li><img src="https://static1.squarespace.com/static/5756358501dbae2c96b689fe/t/5829efb69de4bb1fe2fd2a37/1479143354215/V3DG+Web+Icons-04.png?format=300w" alt"comprehensive services" height="150px"></li>
    <li>ComprehensivevServices</li>
   </ul>
   <ul>
    <li><img src="https://static1.squarespace.com/static/5756358501dbae2c96b689fe/t/5829efc329687f358474b73a/1479143366452/V3DG+Web+Icons-05.png?format=300w" alt"Dependable Support" height="150px"></li>
    <li>Dependable Service</li>
   </ul>
   <ul>
    <li><img src="https://static1.squarespace.com/static/5756358501dbae2c96b689fe/t/5829efd0414fb518a2c06557/1479143379620/?format=300w" alt"Easy To Work With" height="150px"></li>
    <li>Easy To Work With</li>
   </ul>
  </div>
 </section>
```